# How to identify SQL injection issue while passing table name from params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using brakeman gem to identify the sql injection issues in my **rails** project. Found a medium level injection issue with a sql query where i am passing the table name from the params. How do i avoid this issue. I tried surrounding the table name with `(ticks).

Following is the code causing this issue:

```
Student.find_by_sql("select * from students,#{params[:name]} where conditions")
```

Following is what i tried:

```
Student.find_by_sql("select * from students,`#{params[:name]}` where conditions")
```

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.2.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of `"`...

Comment: doesn't rails use prepared statement like things, `?` etc

Comment: Using `find_by_sql` might be a code smell. Can you add a better example what you want to archive and what parts need to be dynamic? At the moment I think `Student.joins(params[:name]).where...` might be a better approach.

Comment: i just wrote an arbitary code @ meager.

Comment: @spickerman,where is not available for the version i am using.

Comment: @argentum47 can not use parameterization for tables. and prepared statement is not available for the version i am using

Comment: @meager it is a legacy code. My work is just to remove the sql injections and not to change it, so cant do anything regarding that.

Comment: @RichaSinha: You are right, but perhaps some sort of `Student.find(:joins => ..., :conditions => ...)`?

Comment: Why do people vote down my question. It is important for me that is why i have posted it here. I want a solution for this if any, otherwise i would not have posted it over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `quote` or `quote_table_name`, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html

How you access these methods will depend on where the code using it is located.

Comment: `quote_table_name` uses `quote_column_name` which ultimately puts a tick around the table name. therefore is not different from what i tried. Brakeman is still detecting this as a sql injection issue.

Comment: You have to separate "a vulnerability is present in the code" from "Brakeman is warning about it". Brakeman is not perfect (no SAST is) and oftentimes cannot detect when valid protections are used. In this case, [quoted_table_name](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/pull/647) will no longer warn. It is *not* equivalent to your code where you manually put backticks around the value even if in simple cases the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Don't interpolate `params` into your SQL statements.

You should be pulling the value out into a variable, and the comparing it against a whitelist:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  KNOWN_GOOD_TABLES = %w(posts records songs items)

  def index
    @table_name = params[:name]

    raise "Invalid table" unless KNOWN_GOOD_TABLES.include?(table_name)

    Student.find_by_sql("select * from students,#{@table_name} where conditions")

  end
end
```

Comment: can not do that, the table name is dynamic. It is a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_table_name(params[:name])`